# My contact form works for most people but sometimes nothing happens

Tags: php, html, ajax, contact-form

I've had the site running for a few days and it seemed to be working just fine, but now there's been complains about it not working.

Here's the html code with some sript on it (i know it's far from ideal, but it was the way I found to make it keep the message on the same page without redirecting to the blnk PHP page saying 'thaks for your contact' before redirecting)

```
<form id="contact-form" class="php-email-form">
    <div class="row gy-4 form">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Your best email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button type="submit"><b>I WANNA JOIN!</b></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="success-message" class="hidden confirmacao" style="color:#fff; font-size: 32px;">
    Thanks for your contact! Redirecting...
</div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        var form = document.getElementById('contact-form');
        
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData(form);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'forms/contact.php');
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {

                    var successMessage = document.getElementById('success-message');
                    successMessage.classList.remove('hidden');
                    
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        window.location.href = 'https://chat.whatsapp.com/';
                    }, 3000);
                } else {
                    console.error('There was an error sending this.');
                }
            };
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$showForm = true;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $toEmail = "mail@email.com";
    $subject = "Contact form recived";

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    if (!empty($name) && !empty($email)) {
        $name = sanitizeInput($name);
        $email = sanitizeInput($email);

        $message = "Nome: " . $name . "\n";
        $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";

        $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n" .
                   "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n" .
                   "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

        if (mail($toEmail, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
    }
}

function sanitizeInput($input) {
    $input = trim($input);
    $input = stripslashes($input);
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
    return $input;
}
```

I really have no idea why this would be working for some people and not for others.